# Find a IVP associated with $y' = y - y^{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The function $g(x, c) = \frac{1}{1-c e^{-x}} $
is a family of solutions (of one parameter) of the first order DE $y'(x) = y(x) - y^{2}(x)$. Find a IVP associated with this differential equation and find the solution corresponding to the initial condition $y(0) = \frac{-1}{3}$

I did the next:

The IVP associated with $y' = y- y^{2}$ is:
$y' - y + y^{2} = 0$ and $y(0) = \frac{-1}{3}$ this is defined in $(- \infty,1) $

I'm not sure if that's right. It's seems incomplete to me.

Comment: The question is missing a lot of context. What is $y_{0}$? Is it the initial condition i.e $y(0) = y_{0}$? Or is it another function $y_{0}(x)$? It might help to note that $g$ solves something 'close' to $y' - y^{2} = 0$, so substituting this in might help illuminate what is going on.

Comment: You're right. I made mistakes when I transcribing the exercise. I already corrected it

Comment: I suppose then that the question is really saying $y = g$ solves $y' = y - y^{2}$ with $y(0) = g(0, c) = 1/(1-c)$. So the associated IVP corresponding to the solution $y = g$ is $$g' = g - g^{2}, \quad g(0, c) = \frac{1}{1-c}$$ Hence, if $$y(0) = -\frac{1}{3} \implies g(0, c) = \frac{1}{1-c} = -\frac{1}{3} \implies c = 4$$ then the solution is given by $$g(x) = \frac{1}{1 - 4e^{-x}}$$

Comment: But $g(x,c)$ is the solution of the ODE $y(x)$. Can I make $g = y$?

Comment: Yes you can. Because (justly) g is a solution of y.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Make the problem simpler switching variables $$y' = y- y^{2}\implies x'=\frac1 {y(1-y)}=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y-1}$$

Integrate both sides and solve for $y$. Now, apply the condition.